# Difference between mosaicking two images and blending two images

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Let's say I have two 1-band images `image1` and `image2`. Is there a difference between

```
ee.ImageCollection([image1, image2]).mosaic()
```

and

```
image1.blend(image2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a mathematical image-processing perspective, they are the same operation — `.mosaic()` is just the version that is intended for processing an arbitrary collection, and `.blend()` is convenient when you only have two images only.

However, their handling of image bands is different: `.blend()` will replicate a single-band image to match the bands of a multi-band image, but mosaicing a collection requires that all images have the same set of band names.